# Unable to select number of entries for page in pagination when linked with other dropdown php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination

Am having 500 records in table am having pagination as showing 100 per page or 200 per page. Am having filter dropdown for category.
At first when I select category dropdown for filtering its showing correct data am showing 100 entries for each page by default. I am having 200 records of a particular category so I selected  200 entries then selected category gone from dropdown and its showing all records.
I have used two seperate forms for entries and category filter.

```
 <div>
             <?php
                // put all your options into an array
              $options = array(0 => 'Select Entries', 500 => 500, 1000 => 1000, 2000 => 2000, 3000=>3000);
             ?>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" style="padding-bottom:10px;" >
                 <select class="selectpicker" name="results" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                 <?php
                    // loop trough the elements
                  foreach($options as $value => $label) {
                      // test if the current value is the posted one...
                          $selected = (isset($_POST['results']) && intval($_POST['results']) === $value) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; 
                          echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.$selected.'>'.$label.'</option>';
                     }
                 ?>
                 </select>
              </form>
            </div>
             <div style="padding-left:200px;">
                 <button>Export</button>
             </div>
            <div style="padding-left:200px;">
               <?php
                // put all your options into an array
                 $filters = array(0 => 'Select based', 1 => 'Pending', 2 => 'Completed');
                ?>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" style="padding-bottom:10px;" >
                 <select class="selectpicker" name="filter_results" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                 <?php
                    // loop trough the elements
                  foreach($filters as $value => $label) {
                      // test if the current value is the posted one...
                          $selected = (isset($_POST['filter_results']) && intval($_POST['filter_results']) === $value) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; 
                          echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.$selected.'>'.$label.'</option>';
                     }
                 ?>
                 </select>
              </form> 
            </div>
   $page_id = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;
                       if(isset($_POST['results']))
                       {
                           $results_per_page = $_POST['results'];

                       }
                        else
                           {
                                $results_per_page = 500;

                            }
                          if(!empty($_POST["filter_results"])) {
                              $filters_1 = $_POST['filter_results'];
                              $query="SELECT * FROM video_data WHERE filter_results = $filters_1";
                         }
                          else
                          {
                             $query="SELECT * FROM video_data"; 
                          }

                        $select_categories=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                        $number_of_categories = mysqli_num_rows($select_categories);
                        $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_categories/$results_per_page);
                         // determine which page number visitor is currently on
                         if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
                                   $page = 1;
                          } else {
                            $page = $_GET['page'];
                             }
                        $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;
                         if(!empty($_POST["filter_results"])) {
                              $filters_1 = $_POST['filter_results'];
                              $sql='SELECT * FROM  video_data WHERE filter_results ='. $filters_1.' ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                              $sql='SELECT * FROM  video_data ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
                         }
```

Comment: You need to show us all the relevant code and let us know where in it your having issues.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson updated code

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson after completing this one I will update it to prepared statments. normal statements has sql injections right compared prepared statements but why every one uses only normal one

Comment: Everyone aren't using "normal one". Everyone that cares about security is using prepared statements, if the queries are using something other than hard coded data, that is. You should rewrite it first, _then_ solve the issue, since rewriting it might fix some issues your having. It's a waste of time debugging something you're gonna rewrite anyway..

Comment: My retina literally burns each time I see people use code unaware of the vulnerability's to build into it. Yes, your code is liable to [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Please read the documentation on how to use prepared statements for [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). If you don't, be prepared that 1 day your database is leaked to the web.

Comment: And if the comment of mine and @magnus is not clear enough, ***fix it***. It is a waste of time for us to fix a broken code. You should learn and I'm not rolling out the red carpet because that ain't learning. I quit reading the moment I saw the improper use `mysqli`. Likely that will be the same for other so'ers. And blah blah blah I will fix it later, is **not** working for me.